# Set of programmatically added images not wrapping

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/wordToFindLayout"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
</RelativeLayout>
```

On which I am programmatically adding images (images of letters), and I would like these images to go to the next line when they reach the right part of the screen (kind of carriage return). I initially don't know how many images will be displayed.

At the moment I just don't see the images exceeding the screen width and I didn't find a way to programmatically know when they reach the right side of the screen.

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the GridView with the property android:numColumns="X" where X is the number of images per row.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Easy and efficient. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to go to next line:https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful !